# Handling promises (rlang) with for loops and ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

The aim of this script was to replicate something like the figure below:
[image: Hydman's Rolling Time series cross-validation]
found on: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/

The problem I have encountered relates to (I think) how R is handling my promises in ggplot.

Below is an example which reproduces my problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
process_starting_row  <- 600
per_validation_period <- 30
number_of_validations <- 5

graphical_data <- data.frame(x= 1:(process_starting_row + 1 + (number_of_validations)*per_validation_period))

for (it in 1:number_of_validations) {

  # For this graph there is always a line and then a colour component explaining each one...
  graphical_data[,paste0("iteration",it,"line")]   <- c(it)

  # First make the whole row grey and then "dolly up" the colours.
  graphical_data[,paste0("iteration",it,"colour")] <- "grey"
  graphical_data[1:(process_starting_row + (it-1)*per_validation_period), paste0("iteration",it,"colour")] <- "blue"
  graphical_data[(process_starting_row + 1 + (it)*per_validation_period), paste0("iteration",it,"colour")] <- "red"

}
#graphical_data
```

The above code creates a dataframe object which could be used to create the desired figure. For each iteration (in the original figure a different line) it creates a vector corresponding to the iterations "height" above the axis (that columns name is always `iteration#line` and a corresponding character vector, `iteration#colour`, with the colour code for each of the dots.

The next bit is to create a base ggplot object.

```
ggbase <- ggplot(data = graphical_data, aes(x=x)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(process_starting_row-1*per_validation_period, nrow(graphical_data))) +
  theme_bw()
```

It is upon this base object that I wish to iterate.

I wrote a function which would add each iteration `gg_adding()` and then another `ggaddfor()` which runs the for loop.

```
gg_adding <- function(data, iteration_sub, color_sub){
  iteration_promise <- enquo(iteration_sub)
  colour_promise <- enquo(color_sub)
  gg  <- geom_point(data = data, aes(x= x, y= !! iteration_promise, color = !! colour_promise))
  return(gg)
}

ggaddfor <- function(data, gg){
  ggout <- gg
for (it in 1:number_of_validations) {
  #print(it)
  iterationsub <- paste0("iteration",it,"line")
  coloursub <- paste0("iteration",it,"colour")

  ggout <- ggout + gg_adding(data, iterationsub, coloursub)

  }
  return(ggout)
}
```

When I run this function I get the following:

```
# Not working
ggaddfor(graphical_data, ggbase)
```

Which produces output that looks like this:
[image: ggaddfor-wrong-output]

Clearly that's not what I was hoping for...
In order to test things I stipulated each iteration explicitly.

```
    # Working...
ggadd <- ggbase
ggadd <- ggadd + gg_adding(graphical_data, iteration1line, iteration1colour)
ggadd <- ggadd + gg_adding(graphical_data, iteration2line, iteration2colour)
ggadd <- ggadd + gg_adding(graphical_data, iteration3line, iteration3colour)
ggadd <- ggadd + gg_adding(graphical_data, iteration4line, iteration4colour)
ggadd <- ggadd + gg_adding(graphical_data, iteration5line, iteration5colour)
```

This produces the desired output:
[image: ggadd_output]

I want to put these functions into a package I'm currently writing and so explicitly stipulating the additions (as I do directly above) is not going to work...

I'm not sure why my earlier code is not producing the same results. I'm somewhat new to handling promises with the rlang package and I suspect my mistake could be there...

Comment: It looks like you are passing strings to your argument, e.g., `iterationsub` in `ggadding()` within `ggaddfor()`.  In that case one option is to replace `enquo()` with `sym()` in your `ggadding()` function.  In your test case you are passing arguments as symbols instead of strings, which is why `ggadding()` works fine there.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks! That sorted it out. It also made the distinction a between the two clearer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me is to replace your `enquo()` calls in your `gg_adding()` function by `as.symbol()`, so that the new function would look like this:

```
gg_adding <- function(data, iteration_sub, color_sub){
  iteration_promise <- as.symbol(iteration_sub)
  colour_promise <- as.symbol(color_sub)
  gg  <- geom_point(data = data, aes(x= x, y= !! iteration_promise, color = !! colour_promise))
  return(gg)
}
```

However, in order to not duplicate your data every iteration, I would suggest this as your `geom_point()` call.

```
gg  <- geom_point(aes(y= !! iteration_promise, color = !! colour_promise))
```

I'm tangentially familiar with tidy evaluation and quotation, but not fully. The thing that I understand is that whatever you put in `aes()`, will always be evaluated in context of `data` column names, first in the layer's data, next in the global data, unless the user is explicit in his calls (e.g `aes(fill = "black")` or something). Because a value for `x` and `data` are already specified in your `ggbase` construction, we do not need it in your `geom_point()` call.

I know this is maybe an unsollicited tip and I apologise, but ggplot seems to prefer to work with long data more than with wide data. What I mean with 'wide' data is that your iterations are sort of `cbind()`-ed together. Therefore, if you first calculate each iteration and then `rbind()` them together, you could shorten your script by quite a bit and circumvent the (quasi)quotation stuff altogether to produce a similar plot:

```
new_gr_dat <- lapply(seq_len(number_of_validations), function(it){
  df <- data.frame(x= 1:(process_starting_row + 1 + (number_of_validations)*per_validation_period),
                   line = it, # doubles as y-value and iteration tracker
                   colour = "grey")
  df[1:(process_starting_row + (it-1)*per_validation_period), "colour"] <- "blue"
  df[(process_starting_row + 1 + (it)*per_validation_period), "colour"] <- "red"
  return(df)
})
new_gr_dat <- do.call(rbind, new_gr_dat)

ggplot(new_gr_dat, aes(x = x, y = line, colour = colour)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(process_starting_row-1*per_validation_period, max(new_gr_dat$x)))
```